RabbitMQ TLS, is a client certificate needed?
Im quite "novice" to all things regarding certificates and TLS.. so this might be a dumb question. I have setup RabbitMQ to use TLS, and according to the web-manager and the logs TLS is enabled. However, I would prefer to use TLS (since I want the communication between my application and RabbitMQ to be encrypted), but I would prefer to only have to use a username and a password. From many examples that I have seen you also need to generate a "client certificate" (which Im not sure of what that is..), but thats an extra step I would prefer not to manage. Is my request even possible? Or am I missing something entirely of how TLS and RabbitMQ works?
